Alien Weekends!
Alien Weekends!
I've crash-landed on another planet! Luckily, the alien society I landed in is almost identical to that of Earth's, except for their timekeeping. Their calendar doesn't use months, so each day is represented by a single nonnegative integer. Each alien week consists of m weekdays followed by an n-day weekend, with the first day of the first week being 0. I'd like to know exactly how many weekdays and weekends are in a week, but I'm too embarrassed to ask.
Fortunately, one of the local aliens started talking about xyr job and mentioned a few days that are part of the week, and a few that are part of the weekend. I'd like some code that could use what xe said in order to tell me how long the week is.

Challenge
Given two disjoint, non-empty lists of distinct nonnegative integers (d and e), output two positive integers m and n such that:

For each weekday di in d, di%(m+n)<m
For each weekend day ei in e, ei%(m+n)>=m

Alternatively, you may output m+n and either m or n. If you wish, you can take input as 1-indexed: that is, the first week starts on 1, (di-1)%(m+n)<m and (ei-1)%(m+n)>=m. If you use an alternative input or output method, mention it in your answer.
You are guaranteed that there exists at least one pair of valid m and n values. If multiple outputs are possible, you may output any of them.

Examples
[0, 3, 4, 8, 11], [5, 6, 12] -> 5, 2

The alien (yet familiar) calendar looks like this:
A  B  C  D  E  F  G
-------------- ~~~~~
0  1  2  3  4  5  6
7  8  9  10 11 12 13

Days A (0), B (8), C, D (3), and E (4, 11) are weekdays, while F (5, 12) and G (6) are weekends. Note that the calendar will always begin on a weekday, and end on a weekend.

[0, 2, 6], [7, 9] -> 1, 1 OR 7, 3/4/5/...

The calendar might look like this:
A B
- ~
0 1
2 3
4 5
6 7
8 9

OR like this:
A B C D E F G H I J
------------- ~~~~~
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

As such, both 1, 1 and 7, 3 are valid outputs. Notably, 7, 4 or 7, [integer greater than 2] are also valid, with none of the mentioned days occurring on the second week.

Samples
These each take 0-indexed input and output m, n.
[0, 3, 4, 8, 11], [5, 6, 12] -> 5, 2
[0, 2, 6], [7, 9] -> 1, 1 OR 7, 3/4/5/...
[3, 14, 1], [5, 9, 26] -> 5, 5 OR 4, 7 OR 5, 9 OR 4, 10
[8, 16, 24], [3, 4, 7, 9] -> 1, 7


In the last test case 1,1 also works.

@pajonk 1,3 as well. And 4,10 and 5,9 work for the third test case as well.

Are both input sets guaranteed to be non-empty? Something like [3,4], [] -> (m=2, n=1) or (m>=5, n>=0) seems reasonable but perhaps you want to exclude such edge cases from the problem? (Note that most of the existing answers do not work properly in such cases.)


that should be (m>=5, n>=1) (due to "output two positive integers").


these should all be fixed now.

Charcoal, 21 bytes
→Ｗ¬›⌊﹪ηⅈ⌈﹪θⅈＭ→Ｉ⟦ⅈ⌊﹪ηⅈ

Try it online! Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs m+n and m. Explanation:
→

Start by guessing that m+n might be 1. (This won't end well...)
Ｗ¬›⌊﹪ηⅈ⌈﹪θⅈ

Until all weekend days follow all weekdays...
Ｍ→

... increment m+n.
Ｉ⟦ⅈ⌊﹪ηⅈ

Output m+n and the earliest weekend day as m.

Python3, 132 bytes
def f(d,e):
 q=[(1,1)]
 for m,n in q:
  if all(i%(m+n)<m for i in d)and all(i%(m+n)>=m for i in e):return m,n
  q+=[(m+1,n),(m,n+1)]

Try it online!

and  -> *; ...<m  -> m>...; ...>=m  -> m<=.... Also, if we don't need to handle empty input sets then we can collapse the two parts to one with all(i%(m+n)<m<=j%(m+n)for i in d for j in e).

JavaScript (V8), 83 bytes
x=>g=(y,i,h=(q,a)=>n=Math.min(...q.map(t=>t*a%i)))=>h(x,-1)+h(y,1)>0?[n,i]:g(y,-~i)

Try it online!
1 layer try
Output m+n, m

I think you're allowed to return [i,n].

05AB1E, 14 bytes
ZLãʒO%yн@εNQ}ß

Input as a pair of lists \$[d,e]\$.
Outputs all valid \$[m,n]\$-pairs within the range \$(1,1)\leq(m,n)\leq(\max(d\mathbin\Vert e),\max(d\mathbin\Vert e))\$. If there are possible test cases for which the output would be outside this range, I can fix it. EDIT: Confirmed by @l4m2 that at least one valid pair can always be found with \$m\leq\min(e)\$ and \$n\leq\max(e)\$ in affect.
Try it online or verify all test cases.
Explanation:
Z              # Push the flattened maximum of the (implicit) input-pair of lists
 L             # Pop and push a list in the range [1,max]
  ã            # Pop and take all pairs of this list
   ʒ           # Filter this list of pairs [m,n] by:
    O          #  Sum the current pair: m+n
     %         #  Modulo all inner values of the (implicit) input by this (m+n)
      yн       #  Push the first item of the current pair
        @      #  >= check on each inner value: i%(m+n) >= m
         εNQ}ß #  Check if the first list only contains 0s, and second list 1s:
         ε     #   Map over this pair of checks:
          NQ   #    Check for each check whether it equals the 0-based max-index
            }ß #   After the map: push the flattened minimum to check all are 1
               # (after which the list of valid pairs is output implicitly)


Must in range at least min(e) >= m, max(e) >= n always possible

@l4m2 Thanks. I've added this observation to my answer. :)

R, 65 63 bytes
\(d,e){while(any(d%%T>=F,e%%T<F)){h=F>T;F=1+F*!h;T=T+h};c(T,F)}

Attempt This Online!
Outputs m+n, m.
